# Tab index not working properly

Tags: .net

I have some controls in the tablelayoutpanel but the tab index for the control are not working properly.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what your specific issue is because the question is a bit vague, but be aware that container controls have seperate tab indexes than child controls.

So if you have a parent control with tab index 0 then you will want the first child control inside that containter that you would like to have focus be tab index 0 as well.

Just for clarification, if you have 3 containers with 3 controls each the indexes should be defined as below for a linear tab order.

```
0:
  0
  1
  2

1:
  0
  1
  2

2:
  0
  1
  2
```